# replace occurance of character between 2 string using mawk only

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, gsub

replace occurance of character in string using mawk

Hi Guys, need this solution using mawk, please help.

I have 2 strings STR_IN & STR_CMPR.
Want to repalce all character of STR_CMPR in STR_IN
main thing is, if STR_IN have some character twice & in STR_CMPR same character is only once then from STR_IN only one character should be replce.

can someone help using mawk only, no other method please.
if it can be achieve using gsub & regex or match & regex then its best. I dont want to run through each character using some loop.

Below are 3 examples with expected output.

#### eg 1 :

`STR_IN="AABBCCDD";`
`STR_CMPR="DBAC";`

if using gsub;
`gsub(STR_CMPR, "", STR_IN);`
result should be, STR_IN = ABCD;

if using match,
result : STR_IN_MATCH_CNT = 4 out of 8;

#### eg 2 :

`STR_IN="DBAC";`
`STR_CMPR="AABBCCDD";`

if using gsub;
`gsub(STR_CMPR, "", STR_IN);`
result should be, STR_IN = blank;

if using match;
result : STR_IN_MATCH_CNT = 4 out of 4;

#### eg 3 :

`STR_IN="DDBBAC";`
`STR_CMPR="AABCCD";`

if using gsub,
`gsub(STR_CMPR, "", STR_IN);`
result should be, STR_IN = DB;

if using match,
result : STR_IN_MATCH_CNT = 4 out of 6;

Comment: Could you please do wrap your codes/samples in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: Done the changes, hopes its fine now.

Comment: If in `STR_CMPR` has any character twice then we need to do substitution twice or it should happen only once? could you please confirm once.

Comment: Knockoff twice.
STR_CMPR  = AABC & STR_IN = BAAAC
Result STR_IN=A

Answer (score -1):

There is no way out of this, a for loop is needed, the quickest is:

```
STR_IN_MATCH_CNT=length(STR_IN)
for(i=1;i<=length(STR_CMPR);++i) sub(substr(STR_CMPR,i,1),"",STR_IN)
STR_IN_MATCH_CNT-=length(STR_IN)
```